# append a string in a file via tcl

Tags: file, unix, tcl

i want to open up a pre-existed file and want to add a string inside the file one line before it sees the word 'exit' inside the file. the word 'exit' will always be the last line inside the file, so we can also see this as " add the string one line above the last line" problem. in other words, I want to append this string inside the file. here is example
Example.tcl (before)

```
AAAAAAA    
BBBBBBB    
CCCCCC    
exit
```

Example.tcl (after)

```
AAAAAAA    
BBBBBBB    
CCCCCC    
new_word_string   
exit
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Could you please include your attempt in the question? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

Open the file for reading, and also open a temporary file:

```
set f1 [open $thefile]
set f2 [file tempfile]
```

Read one line at a time until all lines have been read. Look at the line. If it is the string `"exit"`, print the new string to the temporary file. The write the line you read to the temporary file.

```
while {[set line [chan gets $f1]] ne {}} {
    if {$line eq "exit"} {
        chan puts $f2 $thestring
    }
    chan puts $f2 $line
}
```

Close the file and reopen it for reading.

```
chan close $f1
set f1 [open $thefile w]
```

Rewind the temporary file to the start position.

```
chan seek $f2 0
```

Read the entire contents of the temporary file and print them to the file.

```
chan puts -nonewline $f1 [chan read -nonewline $f2]
```

Close both files.

```
chan close $f1
chan close $f2
```

And we're done.

You could use a string buffer instead of a temporary file with minimal changes, to wit:

```
set f [open $thefile]
set tempstr {}

while {[set line [chan gets $f]] ne {}} {
    if {$line eq "exit"} {
        append tempstr $thestring\n
    }
    append tempstr $line\n
}

chan close $f
set f [open $thefile w]

chan puts -nonewline $f $tempstr
chan close $f
```

Documentation: [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could farm the work out to an external command (Tcl was written as a glue language after all):

```
% exec cat example.tcl
AAAAAAA    
BBBBBBB    
CCCCCC    
exit
% set new_line "this is the new line inserted before exit"
this is the new line inserted before exit
% exec sed -i "\$i$new_line" example.tcl
% exec cat example.tcl
AAAAAAA    
BBBBBBB    
CCCCCC    
this is the new line inserted before exit
exit
```

Comment: @ glenn jackman: your solution seems to be working fine except it adds the new line after the exit , rather than before exit